# Checking if a range of Integer values exists in other Range of Values in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

I've `n` number of strings which contains range of integer values separated by space,

```
String range="2008-2008 2009-2050 2010-2015 2016-2080 ....... etc..";
```

Here I need to know if a particular range is already there in the String, say, Integers in 2010-2015 and 2016-2080 is already a part of 2009-2050. How can this be achieved? 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How exactly is `2016-2080` part of `2009-2050`? You Only a part of the range needs to be within?

Comment: @Emz in 2016-2080, 2016-2050 is a part of 2009-2050.

Comment: @KentHawkings - I'm confused about what I'm supposed to do, can't hardcode it since the String keeps on increasing/decrasing

Answer (score 0):

Convert your string representations to [Guava Range](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Range.html) objects and use the provided methods for checking overlap.